# Import Sqlite Database into device programmatically

Tags: android, sqlite

I have manage to export SQLite database to sdcard now I will appreciate if someone help to Import Sqlite database into device?

i'm newbi in android I have tried a lot without successful.

Edit….

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private static final String SAMPLE_DB_NAME = "TrekBook";
private static final String SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME = "Info";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.button2).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.button3).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.button4).setOnClickListener(this);

}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()) {
    case R.id.button1:
        deleteDB();
        break;
    case R.id.button2:
        exportDB();
        break;
    case R.id.button3:
        createDB();
        break;
    case R.id.button4:
        importDB();
        break;  
    }
}

private void deleteDB(){
    boolean result = this.deleteDatabase(SAMPLE_DB_NAME);
    if (result==true) {
         Toast.makeText(this, "DB Deleted!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } 
}

private void exportDB(){
    File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();
    FileChannel source=null;
    FileChannel destination=null;
    String currentDBPath = "/data/"+ "com.authorwjf.sqliteexport" +"/databases/"+SAMPLE_DB_NAME;
    String backupDBPath = SAMPLE_DB_NAME;
    File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
    File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);
    try {
        source = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
        destination = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
        destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());
        source.close();
        destination.close();
        Toast.makeText(this, "DB Exported!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void createDB() {
    SQLiteDatabase sampleDB =  this.openOrCreateDatabase(SAMPLE_DB_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    sampleDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
            SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME +
            " (LastName VARCHAR, FirstName VARCHAR," +
            " Rank VARCHAR);");
    sampleDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +
            SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME +
            " Values ('Kirk','James, T','Captain');");
    sampleDB.close();
    sampleDB.getPath();
    Toast.makeText(this, "DB Created @ "+sampleDB.getPath(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
}

private void importDB(){
    File f=new File("/data/data/com.authorwjf.sqliteexport/databases/TrekBook");
    FileInputStream fis=null;
    FileOutputStream fos=null;

    try
    {
      fis=new FileInputStream(f);
      fos=new FileOutputStream("/mnt/sdcard/DB/TrekBook");
      while(true)
      {
        int i=fis.read();
        if(i!=-1)
        {fos.write(i);}
        else
        {break;}
      }
      fos.flush();
      Toast.makeText(this, "DB dump OK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
      Toast.makeText(this, "DB dump ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    finally
    {
      try
      {
        fos.close();
        fis.close();
      }
      catch(Exception ioe)
      {}
    }
}

 }
```

activity_main

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="SQLite DB to SD Demo"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Delete" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Export" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Create" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Import" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in advance….

Comment: Hi, Did you got the solution for importing db to sqlite db in android? If yes it will be kind from your end if you will post the answer here.

Comment: Hi, Did you got the solution for importing db to sqlite db in android? If yes it will be kind from your end if you will post the answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
File f=new File("/data/data/com.example.sql/databases/DBNAME");
                    FileInputStream fis=null;
                    FileOutputStream fos=null;

                    try
                    {
                      fis=new FileInputStream(f);
                      fos=new FileOutputStream("/mnt/sdcard/DB/database");
                      while(true)
                      {
                        int i=fis.read();
                        if(i!=-1)
                        {fos.write(i);}
                        else
                        {break;}
                      }
                      fos.flush();
                      Toast.makeText(this, "DB dump OK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                      Toast.makeText(this, "DB dump ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                      try
                      {
                        fos.close();
                        fis.close();
                      }
                      catch(Exception ioe)
                      {}
                    }
```

do not forget to add permission in your manifest.xml

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Thanks Simple Plan for your help, sorry i was away from my computer… let me try now..

Comment: it says, DB dump ERROR

Comment: why?? you change the PATH cross check it carefully.

Comment: It says now "DB Dump OK" but when i test the database its always same data as before..

Comment: you cant override this DB. when you again export DB then you first Delete older DB file from Sdcard .

Comment: I have tried maybe something wrong with my code… let me edit all my code you can test it..

Comment: Your code import or export? look like export? am i right?

Comment: i will appreciate if could help me with import sqlite from sdcard into application...

Answer (score 0):

**Import Sqlite database into device -**

```
try {
            backupDatabase();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }


public static void backupDatabase() throws IOException {
        //Open your local db as the input stream
        String inFileName = "/data/data/com.myapp.main/databases/Content";
        File dbFile = new File(inFileName);
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(dbFile);

        String outFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Content";
        //Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = fis.read(buffer))>0){
            output.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        //Close the streams
        output.flush();
        output.close();
        fis.close();
    }
```

To check this database you have to give command from application path in a console like -

```
adb pull mnt/sdcard/Content
```

where,

Content is what you provided as a `inFileName` above.

Offcourse, you have to change the `inFileName` and `outFileName` as applicable by your application and where you have exported it and where you want to import in a device.

Comment: thanks for your help Ved Prakash, sorry i was away from my computer i have just tested your code not seccessful

Answer (score 0):

Try this Evil way if your device is rooted. Otherwise you cannot pull DB from phone to sdCard:

```
    public void copyDbToSdcard()
{
    try
    {
        String comando = "cp -r /data/data/com.package.name/Databases/DB_File.db /sdcard/Your_Custom_Folder/";
        Process suProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
        DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(suProcess.getOutputStream());
        os.writeBytes(comando + "\n");
        os.flush();
        os.writeBytes("exit\n");
        os.flush();
        try
        {
            int suProcessRetval = suProcess.waitFor();
            if(255 != suProcessRetval)
            {
                Log.e("SU", "If Part");
            }
            else
            {
                Log.e("SU", "Else Part");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.e("ERROR-->", ex.toString());
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Enjoy :)